# I need help with a polynomial long division problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So the problem that I am working on at the moment is the following:

What is $\frac{2z^3-z^2+4z}{3-z}$?

This is my working out so far:

$3-z\overline{)2z^3-z^2+4z} \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \underline{-(6z^2-2z^3)} \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4z^3-7z^2+4z)$

But now I'm confused. Here, you'd usually find out how many times you need to multiply z by to get the answer to the subtraction done above... But in this case, the answer has multiple entries and thus you cannot just give a simple answer like that... What do I do here? Do I see how many times you need to multiply z to get each of the individual terms, add them together, and then multiply that by $3 - z$? Or what else?

I know my calculations are correct...

$z(-) = 2x^3$, $- = 2x^2$,

$2z^2(3-z) = (2z^2(3)) + (2z^2(-z)) = 6z^2 - 2z^3$,

$(2z^3-z^2) - (6z^2-2z^3) = (2z^3-(-2z^3)) + (-z^2-6z^2) = 4z^3 + (-7z^2) = 4z^3 - 7z^2$.

Then I just bring down the $4z$, and that is where I am stuck right now... What am I missing?

I still want to use the division algorithm, so please don't suggest a completely different method :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I cannot make a sense out of your calculations.

The polynomial to divide is $2z^3-z^2+4z$, by $-z+3$.

First partial quotient: $-2z^2$.

Subtract $(2z^3-z^2+4z)-(-2z^2)(-z+3)=5z^2+4z$.

Second partial quotient: $-5z$.

Subtract $5z^2+4z-(-5z)(-z+3)=19z$.

Third partial quotient: $-19$.

Subtract: $19z-(-19)(-z+3)=57$

**Quotient** $-2z^2-5z-19$, **remainder** $57$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is incorrect.  Also, you should always write things in descending degree order:  $-z+3$

Then:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
&-2z^2\\
-z+3&\overline{)2z^3-z^2+4z+0}
\\&2z^3-6z^2
\\&\overline{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;5z^2+4z+0}
\end{array}
$$
See what you can do with that.